# How to switch from Oracle DB to Mongodb?

Tags: oracle, mongodb, data-analysis

I have a question about mongodb. Indeed, I want to switch from oracle dbs to a mongo db in order to have more flexible structure. The goal of my project consists in carrying out some consistent data analysis after implementing a mongoDB which will able to store my data in json format for instance or some useful logs about requests done by my colleagues on a Web service.

Please, what are your tips ? What are the most efficient java frameworks in order to build a solid database ? Need I to learn some other languages ?

Feel free to suggest or to give me our advice on who to start properly with this tool. Any share of your feedback on your experiences with data analytics for BI will be a real pleasure for me.

Thanks... :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are couple of articles that were written exactly for this case: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Many NoSQL databases will give you a more flexible structure. Have you verified that a document DB is actually a good fit for the data you have ? If so then Mongo has drivers for many popular languages - https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/ - use what suits you best. The key is ALWAYS to understand how your data works.

Comment: When moving from RDBMS to MongoDB It's not so much about languages and frameworks; it's about data design.   I recommend you go to mongodb.com and search for migration best practices, tips, etc.   There's a LOT of material to get you started.